# Is it better to use "0" concatenation in Convert.ToInt32() function call

Tags: c#

Is better to use the below statement

Convert.ToInt32("0" + stringValue)

If not then why?

I know that it is better to user int.TryParse() function, which is better, but what about the above statement.

Comment: Why would you *want* to use that construct?

Comment: I don't want to use it as it has string concatenation, but I saw that piece of code , and I want to know reason of using that statement from you people as I am working of someone else code.

Comment: It's bad code.  The person who wrote it was trying to be "too clever"... I'd remove it, and just use TryParse or Convert directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better than what?

Personally, I think that using `Convert.ToInt32("0" + stringValue)` is an anti-pattern.

It doesn't provide anything useful, since:

- A positive integer will still result in the same value.
- If you pass it a negative number, it will throw.
- It doesn't add any extra error checking
- It DOES create an extra string concatenation, which is not used for anything, reducing performance for no reason
- It adds extra complexity for no reason.

Just use `Convert.ToInt32(stringValue)` directly, or `int.TryParse` if you don't want to have exception handling in place.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was half way through typing, but you have a few extra points. I really don't see any reason for it, but can see multiple reasons against it.

Comment: I mean I have seen some code where developer use this statement to convert from string to int value, As you know that int.TryParse is better as it didn't throw execption, In the Convert.ToInt32("0" + stringValue) statment it will not throw execption but as you can see one addition operation of string concatenation is there. that is why I am asking is better approch to use it ?

Comment: It still throws an exception if the string is not an integer. There is no point to that code at all.

Comment: To me, Convert.ToInt32("0" + stringValue) appears to be a typical 'solution' a clueless developer would come up with in order to resolve a common problem (dealing with a possible null reference in this case). 
It is a simple fact that any framework design team will always provide a solution for common problems like this one within the framework itself (a solution like int.TryParse) so to use a 'workaround' like that can only be characterized as clueless IMO...

Comment: @kzen: Hence my "anti-pattern" comment ;)  I agree completely.

Comment: @Kzen, can you explain what is Clueless IMO ?

Answer (score 1):

The only case when that would have any use is if the string variable is a null reference. Concatenating with a zero character is totally pointless, though. As we are only after the null check performed by the string concatenation, a better version would concatenate with an empty string instead, as that doesn't break for negative values:

```
Convert.ToInt32(String.Empty + stringValue)
```

A better solution as it doesn't do a string concatenation:

```
Convert.ToInt32(stringValue ?? String.Empty)
```

An even better solution would be to check for the null value first, so that you don't have to parse the known string:

```
stringValue == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(stringValue)
```